# How to sort queue by integer

Tags: java

I have written a queue ADT but I need to sort the queue with integers descendingly.Here are the codes I have done so far:
Parts of my Codes for Queue:

```
  public class NewPriorityQueue<T> {

  private Node firstNode = null;
  private Node lastNode = null;
  private int queueLength = 0;

  @Override
  public void enqueue(T newEntry, int priority) {
    Node newNode = new Node(newEntry, priority);
    Node current = firstNode;
    if (current != null && newNode.priority > 0) {
      newNode.next = current;
      current = newNode;
    }
    if (isEmpty()) {
      firstNode = newNode;
      lastNode = newNode;
    } else {
      firstNode = current;
    }
    queueLength++;
  }
```

Code for Testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQueueInterface<Character> queue = new NewPriorityQueue<>();
    queue.enqueue('e');
    queue.enqueue('f',10);
    queue.enqueue('g',20);
    queue.enqueue('h',5);
    System.out.print(queue.dequeue());
    System.out.print(queue.dequeue());
    System.out.print(queue.dequeue());
    System.out.print(queue.dequeue());
  }
```

The espected result should be g f h e, but I have no idea how to sort it. Is there any way can sort the queue easily?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are not looping through the queue

```
public void enqueue(T newEntry, int priority) {
    Node newNode = new Node(newEntry, priority);
    Node current = firstNode;

    // if queue is empty, just insert the node
    if (current == null) {
        current = newNode;
        newNode.setNext(null);
    } else {
        Item next = current;
        Item prev = next;

        // loop through the queue to find the correct point of insertion
        do {
            if (priority > next.getPriority()) {
                // break and insert
                break;
            }
            prev = next;
            next = next.getNext();
        } while (next != null);

        newNode.setNext(next);
        // the edge case to see if the newNode has greatest priority
        if (newNode.getPriority() > firstNode.getPriority()) {
            current = newNode;
        } else prev.setNext(newNode);
    }
    queueLength++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think That you are trying to re-invent the wheel. Java gives you almost all of it out of the box. You have several options do choose from

1. Look at [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) class. It implements interfaces of [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). So you can write a class that you want to be your node, say you call it `MyNode` You will need to write your own [Comarator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or make your class implement interface [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Then you create a `List<MyNode> myList = new LinkedList<MyNode>();` You now can use methods sort() of [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) to sort your list and you can use it as your Queue. Simply do Queue myQueue = (Queue)myList; and use it as a Queue
2. Your other option is to use [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) that implements interface [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) and you will hold your nodes in this map with your priorities as keys.

I personally prefer 1st option but it is the mapper of taste.